# Li - Span width issue in IE 10 and Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a problem on IE10 and Chrome - I set a width containing `li span`. Taking the width of the span, I attribute to the `li`. IE misses `1px` for the text ... This problem arises in certain sizes `font-size ex: 18px`, And I can not find where the problem comes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HEY</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
html {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } 

#hp_barreSeek{ background:#f0f0f0; height:37px; width:100%; }
#hp_barreSeekData{ height:37px; width:940px; margin:0 auto 0 auto; }

#hp_barreSeekData ul,#hp_barreSeekData ul li,#hp_barreSeekData ul li span{ 
height:37px; line-height:37px; vertical-align:middle;
display:block;}
#hp_barreSeekData ul{ padding:0 18px 0 18px; }
#hp_barreSeekData ul li{ float:left;  list-style:none;}
#hp_barreSeekData ul li+li{ margin-left:45px;}
#hp_barreSeekData ul li span{  font-size:18px; }
#hp_barreSeekData ul li+li>span{cursor:pointer!important;}
#hp_barreSeekData ul li+li>span:hover,#hp_barreSeekData ul li span.selected{ color:#cacaca;}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="hp_barreSeek">
    <div id="hp_barreSeekData">
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li class="title" ><span>Title</span></li>
                <li id="toto" ><span id="onefx">btn1 hey</span></li>
                <li ><span>btn2</span></li>
                <li ><span>btn3</span></li>
                <li ><span>btn4</span></li>
                <li class="clear"></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#onefx').on('click',function(){
                $('#toto').css('width',$(this).width());
                console.log($(this).width());
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Created this JSFiddle.

```
Visit http://jsfiddle.net/tp4jbj06/
```

Don't see any issues from Safari to Firefox to Chrome

Comment: You have an error on $ to jquery, select jquery 1.7 library and click to run and test your page and u can see on ie the problem in li span... Thanks

Comment: Try a div tag instead of a span tag with a display:inline-block.